# What are enthalpic and entropic forces?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, entropy, physical-chemistry

Am I right when thinking of entropic force to be an entropy minimizing mechanism and enthalpic force to be an energy minimizing mechanism (which is basically an entropy maximization mechanism).

- What's the relation between both? What is the underlying physical principles that govern both and the entropy-enthalpy compensation?
- Does Enthlapic force have implications in Information Theory?
- Is it possible to build like an spin-glass model with these two forces to study the system frustration?

Comment: Possibly addressed [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/386738/).

Comment: entropy *maximizing* mechanism, maybe