# Reversible processes do not change the entropy of the universe. What is with exergonic reactions?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, entropy, reversibility

I have read that in a reversible process, entropy can be transferred but not generated. Such that the entropy of the universe stays constant.
On the other side, there is the Gibbs Energy, which can be defined as $-TdS$, where $dS$ is the change of the entropy of the universe, meaning also an exergonic chemical reaction, for instance, increases the entropy of the universe.
As far as I know, for Gibbs Energy Processes occur under the assumption that they are isothermal and isobaric, as well as proceeding in a reversible manner.
Where do I have the mistake?

[Here](https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry_Textbook_Maps/Supplemental_Modules_(Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry)/Thermodynamics/The_Four_Laws_of_Thermodynamics/Second_Law_of_Thermodynamics) is the source from where I have the $-TdS$ definition

Comment: Can you clarify what your question is? No real macroscale process is reversible; all increase total entropy. [This is equivalent to minimizing the relevant potential](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/386738/why-are-thermodynamic-potentials-minimised/386789#386789), such as the Gibbs free energy. The use of the Gibbs free energy does not assume reversibility, and your definition of it is incorrect; it is $G\equiv H-TS$ or $dG=-S\,dT+V\,dP$ (for a simple closed system).

Comment: -TS=H-TS is derived from the Second Law.It has been corrected now, thanks. Hope my question now makes sense. And the Gibbs energy change is not assumed to be for reversible processes only? I have thought because of the fact that it represents the maximum amount of non-expansive work, it must be proceeding in a reversible manner.

Answer (score 1):

In a reversible process, a system is in thermal equilibrium with its surroundings at every instant of change. As a result the morsel of energy it looses at a temp. $T$ is the morsel of energy surroundings gain at the *same* temp. $T$, hence the net entropy change in reversible processes is zero.

Note that in a reversible process, while the entropy of the universe is unchanged - of the system's isn't.

*If you know about state variables skip to **What this means***  below

While its 'easiest' to calculate entropy change for reversible processes, its numerically same for irreversible processes too that take the system between the same initial and final state. However, its not as easy to calculate.

Observables like these that are path independent and only dependent on the initial and final system state are called state variables. Gibbs free energy is one of them.

W**hat this means is that**

during exergonic reactions, where $\Delta G_{sys}<0$, occurs regardless of the path the system takes, as reasoned above. So reversibility is not a pre-requisite for spontaneous reactions. In fact for reversible processes, $\Delta G_{sys}=0$ as they are always in equilibrium thus technically, not spontaneous.

Hence, for spontaneous reactions that occur irreversibly, there can be a change in entropy of the system and the universe without any contradictions.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It clarified part of my question. The other part is how it would be even possible to go from state 1 to 2 in a reversible manner with respect to delta G. When -TdS, S for the entropy of the universe, is defined as the Gibbs Energy under isothermal and isobaric conditions as life in a human cell for chemical reaction, must mean, a negative change in Gibbs Energy corresponds to an increase in the entropy of the universe. Then this must be a contradiction to the statement that in a reversible process the entropy of the universe does not change?

Comment: @AchillesZehnter Can one not have heat transfer during a reversible process? remember enthalpy change also appears in $\Delta G$

Comment: Mmh, let me ask it differently. If -TdS=dG, S the total entropy of the universe, than in a reversible process no entropy is generated. All the entropy is constant but can be transferred by heat, as far as I know. If a chemical reaction is spontaneous dG<0 and -TdS<0 and therefore dS>0. When dS>0 entropy has been generated, irreversibilites must have been occured. If they have occured it was not reversible. I understand that it can change in the system by heat transfer but then for a reversible process it must change by the same amount in order to keep the entropy of the universe the same?

Comment: In this source they say that is -TdS which would then be what you have said.https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry_Textbook_Maps/Supplemental_Modules_(Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry)/Thermodynamics/The_Four_Laws_of_Thermodynamics/Second_Law_of_Thermodynamics

Comment: @AchillesZehnter I think you are absolutely right...in reversible processes, the system is in equilibrium and for systems in equilibrium, $\Delta G=0$.

Comment: I think I got it. But first, I think more about it. I will answer then again, when I think I got it really. Huge thanks for your patiency and answers!

Comment: @AchillesZehnter so you doubt was: "1. reversible processes don't gen. entopy. 2. exergonic do 3. gibbs change is reversible - how to reconcile" the only flaw is to assume change in gibbs is reversible. As u stated $..\Delta S_{uni}$ that's definitely not-reversible

Comment: Therefore, if I started with 100 reactants and the reaction is exergonic, as well as in eqilibrium I would have a ratio of reactants to products of 78:22. Then the system fails to return to 100 reactants, meaning the transition from 100 to 78:22 generated entropy?

Comment: @AchillesZehnter u had posted an earlier comment - something along the lines of "all reactions that proceed must be irreversible as reversible ones are at equilibrium anyways"...something like that...may you plz re-post it? I would like to elaborate on that and make that part of the main answer

Answer (score 1):

For the typical case of a reaction process that is carried out reversibly, going from pure reactants at T and P to pure products at T and P, the $\Delta G$ refers to the change in Gibbs free energy of the system (i,e, the chemicals participating in the reaction), not the universe.  The change in free energy of the universe in such a situation is zero, with $\Delta H_{system}=-\Delta H_{surroundings}$ and $\Delta S_{system}=-\Delta S_{surroundings}$.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. But if a reaction goes to completion it is considered to be irreversible and spontaneous, respectively.

Comment: https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Introductory_Chemistry/Book%3A_Introductory_Chemistry_(CK-12)/19%3A_Equilibrium/19.09%3A_Nonreversible_Reactions

Comment: You are confusing reversible chemical reactions with reversible processes.  You do know the difference, right?  The word "reversible" has to entirely different contexts.  Also, all chemical reactions are reversible to some extent, unless their standard Gibbs free energy change is minus infinity.  Also, considering a reaction spontaneous if its Gibbs free energy is negative is just a crude rule of thumb.

Comment: No, sorry. I considered them to be equal. I have some difficulty with the exact english translations for my language. I meant with reversible process the process when one starts with 100 reactants in an exergonic reaction, for example, and ends up with 78:22 ratio for reactants to products, when the system is at chemical equilibrium. The question was whether it is possible that this reaction proceeds reversibly to the chemical equilibrium and back to the initial state of 100 products in this case.

Comment: *...free energy of the system (i,e, the chemicals participating in the reaction), not the universe* yep that's the immediate reaction I had too, but as stated in OP's reference, $\Delta G$ can also be defined as $-T\Delta S_{uni}$ - afet all it *must* have some correlation to $\Delta S_{uni}$ to be deemed the arbiter of spontaneity of a reaction.  In light of this, the OP is right to bring into his arguments $\Delta S_{uni}$

Comment: It is possible to carry out the process of going from 100% reactants to 78.22 ratio for reactants to products reversibly, but the setup and steps to do this are not straightforward, and, for example, might involve compressors, semi=permeabile membranes, a Van't Hoff, equilibrium box, and reversible expansions.

Comment: @lineage It is possible to define a $\Delta G$ for the universe as  $\Delta H_{uni}-T\Delta S_{uni}$ if all the heat transfer between system and surroundings is at temperature T, but, for a reversible process, this is zero.

Comment: @lineage So,....?  What is your point?

Comment: @ChetMiller was merely justifying OP's use of $\Delta S_{uni}$.

Comment: @ChetMiller reversible $\implies \Delta G=0$..never disagreed...i hope that was clear