# Does increasing dynamic pressure of moist air increase condensation?

Tags: pressure, evaporation, condensation

In a pressure cooker, increasing static pressure causes evaporation of water to be less thermodynamically favorable, and increases the rate of condensation of water. This is because water molecules have to overcome a greater pressure to escape the body of liquid water.

The first part of my question is, do I have all that right?

The second part is, assuming I do have that right, is the same true for dynamic pressure or does only static pressure influence evaporation and condensation?

Comment: What is dynamic pressure?

Comment: @David https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_pressure

"It can be thought of as the fluid's kinetic energy per unit volume. "

It's dimensionally equivalent to static pressure and gets used in engineering. You can also think of it as the pressure that would be produced by a flowing fluid once it stagnates against a surface.

Comment: I read a bit of the link, and noticed this partial statement in the first sentence: "In incompressible fluid dynamics".  Steam is compressible.

Comment: Yes. At the same time, air at slow enough speeds does approximately follow the Bernoulli equation and you can talk meaningfully about dynamic pressure. See the picture and caption from the link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_pressure#/media/File:VenturiFlow.png

Comment: "*In a pressure cooker, increasing static pressure causes evaporation of water to be less thermodynamically favorable...do I have all that right?*" You do not have this part right. Increasing the pressure on condensed matter very slightly [*increases*](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/649187/what-is-the-effect-of-atmospheric-pressure-on-the-vapour-pressure-of-water/649214#649214) the equilibrium vapor pressure.

Comment: I suspect that there is something that you have in mind, but I can't tell what it is.  Can you be more specific in your question?