# Doubt in the spontaneous process definition

Tags: reversibility

Using the following definition I don't understand why a reversible process is not spontaneous. For an isolated system, a reversible process happen without any outside intervention.

**reversible process:** the system changes in such a way that the system and surroundings can be put back in their original states by exactly reversing the process.

**Spontaneous processes**: those that can proceed without any outside intervention.

Answer (score 0):

A spontaneous process is like a ball rolling downhill. Forces push the ball in the downhill direction. The ball will gain kinetic energy. You would have to put that energy back to reverse it.

A reversible process is like a ball rolling on the level. The ball proceeds without gaining or losing kinetic energy. It could go the other way in the same fashion.

Answer (score 0):

This question can possibly be addressed *without* invoking entropy, but entropy provides a simple resolution for many-particle systems.

All spontaneous processes require a nonzero driving force to push them to occur at any finite rate. This force can be generalized as a gradient; i.e., a difference in temperature or pressure or surface tension or electric field or chemical potential—any [intensive property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intensive_and_extensive_properties). (For example, we can't put identical-temperature systems in contact and expect to obtain net heat flow.)

[Entropy is generated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_production) whenever energy is transferred down a gradient. Entropy is related to the distribution of energies, and the state at the bottom of the gradient gains more distributional possibilities for a given energy than the state at the top of the gradient loses. (To return to the heat transfer example, isothermal cooling of a hot object at temperature $T_\mathrm{H}$ [removes entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat#Heat_and_entropy) $\Delta S=Q/T_\mathrm{H}$ for heat transfer $Q$, but isothermal heating of a cold object at temperature $T_\mathrm{C}$ contributes entropy $\Delta S=Q/T_\mathrm{C}$. Since $T_\mathrm{H}>T_\mathrm{C}$, entropy has been generated in the process of allowing heat to move down the temperature gradient.)

Unfortunately, the Second Law tells us that entropy can't be destroyed; it's too unlikely for the energy distribution of a many-particle system to independently squeeze into a tighter profile.

Reversible processes must therefore generate no entropy, as we would not be able to return the system and surroundings to the original state—there would be an entropy excess.

**Thus, a spontaneous process can never be reversible.** ([One can even show](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/386789/146039) that [spontaneity as characterized by free energy minimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spontaneous_process) implies [entropy maximization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_maximum_entropy). For instance, all chemical reactions must either produce higher-entropy products or must heat their surroundings, which increases *their* entropy.)

Why, then, would we ever consider reversible macroscale processes if they can never occur in reality? Because it's convenient to not worry about that finite amount of entropy being created as a function of the process speed and conditions. (Put another way, it's annoying to work with a one-sided conservation law; energy, in contrast, satisfies two-sided or absolute conservation in essentially all contexts.) And in any case, we could come arbitrarily close to reversibility with careful design and by running a process very slowly, so an analysis assuming reversibility isn't completely ludicrous. (Returning again to the heat transfer example, we assume that a very slight temperature difference drives heat flow spontaneously and with negligible entropy generation in a nearly reversible process.)