# Second law of thermodynamics in non-mechanical situations

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy, chemical-potential

what is the form of second law of thermodynamics in other situations, like chemical, electrical reactions? I know Gibbs energy works just for constant temperature and pressure, but what about other conditions?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why are thermodynamic potentials minimised?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/386738/)

Comment: That link translates total entropy maximization (which always holds) to minimization of the appropriate potential. You'd define this potential as appropriate; for constant volume, constant temperature $T$, constant matter, and constant electric field $E$, for example, the potential $\Phi\equiv U-TS-EP$ is a candidate for minimization (energy $U$, entropy $S$, electrical polarization $P$). Generally, you subtract from $U$ the relevant conjugate pairs (the volume and amount of material are already natural variables for $U$). Does this get at what you're asking about?