# Why do atoms want to attain stability?

Tags: thermodynamics, particle-physics, nuclear-physics, atomic-physics

So, back in my school, our teacher was teaching **structure of an atom**. I had some doubts, like why do hot objects emit radiations and so many. I noticed that every question I had asked had an answer. If I added a why to it, thats another question. It mostly came to a conclusion that *all atoms want to attain stability.* My question is why atoms want to attain stability and can I relate it to *entropy?*

Comment: atoms have no volition so they cannot "want". If atoms were not stable we would not exist here able to discus their stability!

Comment: @annav, Indeed! :)  This potential psychological fallacy does often confuse people. :)

Comment: Energy minimization is derived from entropy maximization in [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/386789/146039).